# .ppt file created on a Mac using PowerPoint 12 can't be opened in OpenOffice or NeoOffice

Tags: macos, openoffice, microsoft-powerpoint, presentations, neooffice

Is it possible to save a file in Microsoft PowerPoint 12 in a format that can be opened by OpenOffice or NeoOffice? I get the error message "Input/output error" when I try to open the file with OpenOffice.

I can open other `.ppt` files in OpenOffice. I tried changing extension to `.pptx` and the same error occured.

Comment: Did you actually change the file-type, or just rename the file?

Answer (score 0):

The newer .ppt files should be in XML format, I believe, but they still contain embedded binary sections that are hard/impossible for other office suites to interpret due to not being in the specs published by Microsoft. However, if you save your Office documents in OpenDocument formats (.odp for presentations), then OpenOffice and NeoOffice should have no problem opening them.

Comment: Thanks.  I've emailed your response to the guest speaker who sent me the ppt.  I'll let you know what happens.